# Resize and round Image before upload PHP

Tags: php, image, input

When someone upload an image with

```
<input type="file"/>
```

I want to resize (like 64x64 for example) and to round it (like border-radius in css) and upload the ronded image.
Someone know if it's possible please? Thank you !

Comment: Well if you want to do it *before* uploading there is no way to do it with PHP because PHP is server side.

Comment: Yes, it is. With javascript (canvas).